# How to tranform this equation to given result?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

following is the mathematical equation that I want to transform to a given result.

Equation: 
$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right|=\ln\left|x\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln\:\frac{1}{3}$

Expected Result: 
$\ y = \frac{3+x^2}{3-x^2} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying by $2$ and using that $\log{(1/3)}=-\log{3}$,
$$ \log{\left| \frac{y-1}{y+1} \right|} = 2\log{\lvert x\rvert} - \log{3} = \log{(x^2/3)}. $$
Exponentiating,
$$ \left| \frac{y-1}{y+1} \right| = \frac{x^2}{3}. $$
The left-hand side must be nonnegative since the right-hand side is the square of a real number, so we either have
$$  \frac{y-1}{y+1} = \frac{x^2}{3} \qquad \text{or} \qquad \frac{y-1}{y+1} = -\frac{x^2}{3}. $$
Now solve for $y$ as usual, treating both cases separately.

Comment: thanks. now how to solve for y?

Comment: Multiply by $y+1$, subtract so that you have all the things multiplying $y$ on one side and not multiplying $y$ on the other, then divide by the coefficient of $y$.

Comment: The left has to be positive with the absolute value signs, but the insides could be negative.  You could have $y=-0.9, RHS=19, x=\sqrt{57}$, for example

Comment: @RossMillikan True, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right|=\ln\left|x\right|+\frac{1}{2}\ln\:\frac{1}{3}
\iff
\ln\sqrt{\left|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right|}=\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |x|\right)
$$
so we have:
$$\sqrt{\left|\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} |x|
$$
squaring (with $\frac{y-1}{y+1}\ge 0$):
$$
3(y-1)=x^2(y+1)
$$
that, solving for $y$ gives:
$$
y=\frac{x^2+3}{3-x^2}
$$

You can see the case $\frac{y-1}{y+1}< 0$